# Select all "visible" worksheets (to print to pdf)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following in an existing app and this works fine as is to print particular worksheets to a pdf:

```
Sheets(Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")).Select
```

I'm trying to print an array of just my **"visible"** worksheets.

I've searched for a solution but can't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, it should do what you are looking for.

```
Sub SelectSheets()
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Visible = True Then
            ReDim Preserve myArray(j)
            myArray(j) = i
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Sheets(myArray).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like I needed. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Randy. You can mark it as the correct answer to close the post if you wish :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A short approach that uses the `False` argument to add to an existing selection:

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
 If ws.Visible Then ws.Select False
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(GetVisibleWorksheetsNames(ThisWorkbook)).Select

End Sub


Function GetVisibleWorksheetsNames(wb As Workbook) As String()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsNames() As String
Dim iV As Long

With wb
    ReDim wsNames(1 To .Worksheets.Count)
    For Each ws In .Worksheets
        If ws.Visible Then
            iV = iV + 1
            wsNames(iV) = ws.name
        End If
    Next ws
    ReDim Preserve wsNames(1 To iV)
End With

GetVisibleWorksheetsNames = wsNames
End Function
```

Comment: very similar to what Brendan Gooden posted while I was writing my solution. the differences lay functionally in that it's more general (you can specify the workbook you need visible sheets names from) and more reusable (you can call it form your code more time without having to rewrite it). From the coding optimization point of view in that it uses `ReDim` only twice, it uses a String array instead of a Variant one. most of what above may not be felt by the user but I think they're good coding habits.

Comment: I inadvertently hit the button to note your solution was not useful. I reversed it immediately, sorry. I'll give your solution a try. Much appreciated.