# Ignoring Hidden Sheets In Arrays

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently producing a workbook that allows the users to print different reports for different departments.

The workbook has multiple copies of the same sheet for different phases of with the user may only need to use 1 or 2 phases out of a potential of 8 phases.

I have added a form that appears once the print has been pressed that allows users to select a report they would like to print which selects the relevant sheet before printing.

This is the code I have be trying to get to work it ignores the hidden sheets but only prints the current sheet and not the sheets visible within the array.

```
Sub SelectSheets()
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 0
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
       If Sheets(i).Visible = True And IsInArray(Sheets(i).Name, Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")) Then
       ReDim Preserve myArray(j)
           myArray(j) = Sheets(i).Name
           j = j + 1
       End If
    Next i
    Sheets(myArray).Select
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant)
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Matt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select all "visible" worksheets (to print to pdf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047183/select-all-visible-worksheets-to-print-to-pdf)

Comment: The code above selects all visible sheets that are also named either Sheet1, 2 or 3. I assume this is intentional? Also, If you're then printing, make sure that you're printing all active sheets and not using a different setting that causes your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this code.

```
Sub SelectSheets()

    Const ExcludedSheets As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"

    Dim SelectedSheets() As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveWorkbook
        ReDim SelectedSheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        i = -1
        For Each Ws In .Worksheets
            If InStr(1, ExcludedSheets, Ws.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                If Ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                    i = i + 1
                    SelectedSheets(i) = Ws.Name
                End If
            End If
        Next Ws

        If i > -1 Then
            ReDim Preserve SelectedSheets(i)
            .Worksheets(SelectedSheets).Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The code below would print the sheets rather than select them.

```
Sub PrintSelectedSheets()
    ' 24 Jan 2018

    Const ExcludedSheets As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3"

    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For Each Ws In .Worksheets
            If InStr(1, ExcludedSheets, Ws.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                With Ws
                    If .Visible = xlSheetVisible Then .PrintOut
                End With
            End If
        Next Ws
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Works ignoring the hidden sheet but only prints the active sheet. How can I get to it print the visible sheet with in the array.  Automatically for example if Sheet1 is hidden when I run the print macro is still automatically prints Sheet2 & Sheet3?

Comment: Surely that question can't be answered without knowledge of your print macro. The presumption should be that it is programmed to print only the ActiveSheet. However, it appears convoluted to first select all sheets and then print selected sheets. I have added code above to directly print the sheets you intended to select.